# ARDUINO DUE& SRF10 ultrasonic sensor

Tags: arduino

I am trying to configure ARDUINO DUE with a SRF10 ultrasonic sensor. I have my code ready but while checking the code, I am getting the error below.
*assertion "(address & 0x80) == 0" failed: file "../source/twi.c", line 261, function: TWI_StartWrite
Exiting with status 1.* Any advice about what to look for to sort out this problem?

Comment: my code for the same configuration is

Comment: Please don't post all 261+ lines of your code.

Comment: Paste it on pastebin and add the link in your question so people here don,t get nervous.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem related to the Arduino Due and how it handles the TWI addresses.

[Here on the Arduino Forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=136105.0) there's a thread about it, it is going to help you

Answer (score 0):

pls review
http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=136105.0

and make sure u use the wire.h for DUE under **arduino\hardware\arduino\sam\libraries\Wire**